# Resize image being parsed from JSON

Tags: css, json

I am parsing data from a JSON, where one of the fields on the table is an image. 
Although, I want that image to fit a specific size.
I have already made so many changes, that I got lost why it doesn't work.

JSON

```
    var products=[];

$.getJSON('products.json',function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i, f){
        var tblRow = "<tr><td class='prod_img'><img src=" + f.image_url + "></td></tr>" + "<tr><td class='title'>" + f.title + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td class='price'>" + f.price + "</td>" + "<td class='price_org'>" + f.old_price + "</td>" + "<td class='add_cart'><img src='img/buynow-green-5.png'>" + "</td></tr>"

        $(tblRow).appendTo("#list_products tbody");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#list_products{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
border: 5px solid #B9FFFF;
margin-top:80px;}
.prod_img{
height:200px;
width:300px;}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a height and width on the img tag instead of the td?

Comment: I was just plain stupid from tiredness.

Answer (score 0):

So, after sleeping some hours, I finally realized what was missing.

I had a tag for the image container, but no for the image.

Sometimes, the answer is simple. You just need to go away for a moment.